# issue with prevent form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, preventdefault

i got currently an issue which i cant solve, i have a form which is submitted via Javascript, but i cant prevent it, could you help me. I provided smallest reproducible script.
Thanks in advance.

```
<form name="f" id="f" action="asd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<script> 
    document.getElementById('f').addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
    }, true);

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.getElementById('f').submit()
    }, false )
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search the documentation of `HTMLFormElement.submit` and i found that `submit` event is not fired by using the `form.submit`. You must use `form.requestSubmit` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the code execution flow. It submit the form before the event listener is added.

To let time for you code to add event listener. I recommand you to execute your submit in the `document.onready` event.
Here is a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/7453uvt6/7/

Comment: i checked your fiddle it didnt work, the onready was not fired, if you replace onready with 

setTimeout( () => {
  document.getElementById('f').submit()
},4000)


i created an example

https://codepen.io/kliefadas/pen/ExNZXaB

Comment: Yep my bad it is updated, use window.onload => https://jsfiddle.net/5qp8bkj2/3/

Comment: If you have a look at your fiddle, you see, that submit prevention didnt work

Comment: The event which you console is never written, seems almost bug of browsers